# Matlab: selecting a number 'i' with a probability 'i' in matlab

Tags: matlab, probability

I am stuck at a problem in matlab. How do I select a number 'i' with a probability 'i' in a matrix.
I want to do this in a matrix, where I select a number 'i' from each row, with probability 'i'.

Any help is appreciated

a sample matrix( dont need to select zeros):

```
    w1= .47;
    w2= .023;
    m1= .06;
    m2= .037;
    x=rand(1,m1)<=m1;
    tolerance= 0.01;

    Transition=[m1 w1 0  w1 0  0   0;
        0  m1 w1 0  0  0   0;
        0  0  m1 w1 0  0   0;
        0  0  0  m2 w2 0   0;
        0  0  0  0  m2 w1  w1;
        0  0  0  0  0  m1  w1
        0  0  0  0  0  0   m1];
```

Comment: what is the meaning of selecting a number i=6 with probability i=6 ? probabilities are bound from 0 to 1 as far as I can tell. Maybe you mean a number `i` with probability `1/i`?

Comment: no no, thats not what I mean. see, if 0.06 gets selected from the Transition matrix, its has to be selected with 0,06 probability! that's what i cant figure out.

the matrix contains values from 0 to 1 only.

Comment: so all your numbers are bound [0,1]...

Comment: yes! I cant figure the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we could calculate a matrix of cumulative probabilities `Tc` in preparation for a strategy that finds the first column exceeding a random value between 0 and 1.

```
Tc = zeros(size(T));
Tc(:, 1) = T(:, 1);
for k = 2 : size(T, 2)
  Tc(:, k) = Tc(:, k - 1) + T(:, k);
end
```

To now draw numbers from each row, we first draw `p = rand(size(T, 2), 1)` and then find the column for which `p` falls into a bucket of cumulative probability:

```
for k = 1 : size(T, 1)
  col = find(T(k, :) > p(k), 1, 'first');
  if isempty(col)
    fprintf('nothing drawn for row %d\n', k);
  else
    fprintf('row %d, col %d, p = %f\n', k, col, T(k, col));
  end
end
```

This works because order does not matter. For example, for some p = 0.2, some arbitrary cumulative distribution could increase from 0.65 to 0.85. The probability for `rand` to yield a value in this interval is indeed 0.2. If this is the last non-zero entry of `T`, `rand` will return a value with 0.15 probability for which no number is drawn. In another example, if all entries in `T` are zero, the cumulative distribution will never exceed what can be drawn by `rand`. For a last example, if there are two entries at 0.5, each, the cumulative distribution will exceed what's drawn by `rand` half and half at either column.

Comment: can @s.bandara please explain! the numbers are drawn, yes, but are they drawn with the same probability, I fail to understand! :(\

Comment: Does the last paragraph clarify this?

Comment: yes, I get it now, @s.bandara, i get it now, and the rows in which nothing is drawn because zero is selected, right??

Comment: Correct. The cumulative distribution never exceeded the result from `rand` in such a case. The extreme case of that where that is guaranteed is when all entries are zero. I added a few more cases to make this more intuitive. See edits.

Comment: Let me know if it works. I don't have MATLAB at my hands right now, but will check tomorrow.

Comment: why is that at times nothing is drawn even when there are no zeroes in a matrix?

Comment: Could you check if `all(sum(T, 2) == 1)`? If that's not the case you would indeed expect nothing to be drawn at times. Only if the sum of all probabilities along a row is 1 you would expect always some number to show up.

Answer (score 1):

So let's start with a hint.
Say you have only one number `0.06` and you want a vector (= one row in a matrix), that this number is scattered such there is `0.06` probability to pick it. A simple solution will be to start with a vector of a 100 zeros `v=zeros(100,1)` and then put at 6 random location the number `0.06`, i.e.

```
ind=randi(100,1,6);
v(ind)=0.06;
```

can you think of a way to extend that to more than one number per row?

Comment: thats a smart way to put up,
although, can I just randomly select a number from the given matrix?
         
        for i=1:7 

        while(1)
            sel=randi(7);
            if((Dij(i,sel) ~= 0))
    show(i)=sel;
    
                break;
            end
        end

        %Dij(i,sel)=Dij(i,sel)-tolerance*(i ~= sel);
        NewDij=Dij;
        
    end

I did this, but it selects a number randomly, not with a probability